Как в vite при запуске build исключался(не создавался) index.html?
Помогите настроить vite чтобы при запуске build исключался(не создавался) index.html?
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export default defineConfig({
    root: resolve(__dirname, 'src/admin'),
    plugins: [],
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                autoprefixer({})
            ]
        },
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                api: 'modern-compiler'
            }
        }
    },
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: 'terser',
        emptyOutDir: false,
        assetsDir: '',
        assetsInlineLimit: 0,
        outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'install/assets'),
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                manualChunks: false,
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
                chunkFileNames: 'js/admin.min.js',
                entryFileNames: 'js/admin.min.js',
                assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
                    if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? '')) {
                        return 'css/admin.min.css';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080
    }
})

Чтобы в результате получал 2 файла:
✓ 630 modules transformed.
../../install/assets/css/admin.min.css    0.35 kB │ gzip:   0.11 kB
../../install/assets/js/admin.min.js    458.05 kB │ gzip: 129.77 kB

Без index.html:
../../install/assets/index.html           0.36 kB │ gzip:   0.25 kB


https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode, https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-lib
